# How to validate Hugging Face organization token?

Tags: curl, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

`/whoami-2` endpoint returns `Unauthorized` for organization tokens, the ones that start with `api_...`.

```
$ curl https://huggingface.co/api/whoami-2 -H "Authorization: Bearer api_<token>"
> { "error": "Unauthorized" }
```

At the same time I can use the same token to get private models. Should I use some other endpoint to validate the tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are requesting to the wrong endpoint. It seems the endpoint is updated and I got a similar error with sending requests to the older endpoint (`whoami`).

just send the request to `whoami-v2` like:

```
$ curl https://huggingface.co/api/whoami-v2 -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}"
> {"type": "","name":"sadra","fullname":"sadra","email":"","emailVerified":true,"plan":"","periodEnd":,"avatarUrl":"","orgs":[]}
```

NB: According to [docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/api-inference/quicktour), it seems old tokens were `api_XXX` or `api_org_XXX`, while all new ones start with `hf_XXX`. So, maybe creating a new token might be helpful if you still face issue with new endpoint.

So, same thing happens for organization tokens:

```
$ curl https://huggingface.co/api/whoami-v2 -H "Authorization: Bearer api_org_XXX"
> {"type":"org","name":"testmy","fullname":"testorg","email":null,"plan":"NO_PLAN","periodEnd":null,"avatarUrl":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1bd0170cca6f638f0dd02c6a79e8c270?d=retro&size=100"}
```

Comment: I've created a new organization to test. The new token starts with `api_org_XXX` and returns `Unauthorized` on `/whoami-v2`

Comment: @dmigo just tested with organization's api and added to the answer, I did not have any problem. maybe try `invalidate and refresh` token from https://huggingface.co/organizations/testmy/settings/tokens` ?

Comment: It works, seems like I was doing something wrong on the previous attempt.